# how to scroll down a div when ajax is success?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am developing a chat page, i am using ajax for sending messages and displaying the chat. i want to scroll down the div when the message is send.

this is my div

```
<div id="messages">
<div>
<img src="">
<label>Sender name</label>
<p>message</p>
</div>
</div>
```

this is my ajax

```
$("#btn_post").click(function(e){ //send message button id 
        $('#ajax_loader').show();
        $.ajax({
            url:'messages/insert_group_messages',
            type: "POST", 
            data: $('#frmGroupMessage').serialize(),
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(){        
                $('#messages').load('group_name/new_messages/'+$('#group_id').val()).fadeIn("slow");
                $('#messages').scrollTop($('#messages')[0].scrollHeight); // i tried this to scroll down but its not working.
                $('#ajax_loader').hide();
           },
           error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError); 
           }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
```

Message is inserting and showing, but its not scrolling down to show the new message.
can anyone help me.

Comment: You're making an asynchronous call in the `success` of an asynchronous call. I imagine your `scrollTop()` is executing before the DOM has rendered it's `.load()`. Use the complete parameter to ensure that it executes in order. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: ya.i understand..thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$("html,#messages").animate({ scrollTop:$('#messages').prop("scrollHeight"))}, "slow");
```

**Or**

```
$('#messages').load('group_name/new_messages/'+$('#group_id').val()).fadeIn("slow",function(){
    $("html,#messages").animate({ scrollTop:$('#messages').prop("scrollHeight"))}, "slow");
});
```

Comment: @ABTech Welcome :-)